# I need help web-scraping

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

So I wanted to scrape visualizations from visual.ly, however right now I do not understand how the "show more" button works. As of now, my code will get the image link, the text next to the image, and the link of the page. I was wondering how the "show more" button functions, because I was going to try to loop through using the number of pages. As of now I do not know how i would loop through each one individually. Any ideas on how I could loop through and go on to get more images than they originally show you????

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2  
import HTMLParser
import urllib, re

counter = 1
columnno = 1
parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://visual.ly/?view=explore&   type=static#v2_filter').read())

image = soup.findAll("div", attrs = {'class': 'view-mode-wrapper'})

if columnno < 4:
    column = image[0].findAll("div", attrs = {'class': 'v2_grid_column'})
    columnno += 1
else:
    column = image[0].findAll("div", attrs = {'class': 'v2_grid_column last'})

visualizations = column[0].findAll("div", attrs = {'class': '0 v2_grid_item viewmode-item'})

getImage = visualizations[0].find("a")

print counter

print getImage['href']

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(getImage['href']).read())

theImage = soup1.findAll("div", attrs = {'class': 'ig-graphic-wrapper'})

text = soup1.findAll("div", attrs = {'class': 'ig-content-right'})

getText = text[0].findAll("div", attrs = {'class': 'ig-description right-section first'})

imageLink = theImage[0].find("a")

print imageLink['href']

print getText

for row in image:
    theImage = image[0].find("a")

    actually_download = False
    if actually_download:
        filename = link.split('/')[-1]
        urllib.urlretrieve(link, filename)

counter += 1
```

Comment: Do you have the Web Developer toolbar installed for your browser? I find it's invaluable for visualizing (pun not intended) form data, button actions, links, etc.

Comment: If you print link is it pointing to the correct resource? That would be the first step to debug.

Comment: No i do not have the web developer toolbar, unless you mean firebug?

Comment: Yeah it is but sometimes it also points to something I don't want. Idk why but sometimes it data-scrapes two different things with the exact same code.

Comment: What if you try using something like wget (http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)? Unless you need some specific processing of the HTML you can download the whole site if you want. You can use sed (http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) to rewrite the links.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a urllib-parser combo here because it uses javascript to load more content.  In order to do this you will need a full force browser emulator (with javascript support).  I have never used [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) before, but I have heard that it does this, as well as has a [python binding](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/)

However, I have found that it uses a very predictable form

```
http://visual.ly/?page=<page_number>
```

for its GET requests.  Perhaps an easier way would be to go under

```
<div class="view-mode-wrapper">...</div>
```

to parse the data (using the above url format).  After all, ajax requests must go to a location.

Then you could do

```
for i in xrange(<whatever>):
    url = r'http://visual.ly/?page={pagenum}'.format(pagenum=i)
    #do whatever you want from here
```